# Login Failed for user 'Server-Name\Guest'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, clickonce

Here's my connection string

```
Data Source=PNJK-SERVER;Initial Catalog=PNJKDC;Integrated Security=True
```

but when I deployed it to another computer this error appears --> http://prntscr.com/atlzdp

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause of the error are:

1) It will cause error if you have different SQL Instance for the other computer which is 99% possible. So your instance for the other computer will also be changed, and make sure that the DB PNJKDC also exist in that computer

2) If you are connected to a network and let's say you configured the whole networking thing e.g.(firewall, ports) the port number might be used by other processes in your computer, you need to change it to different port.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new user on the deployed machine's sql server instance, assign the user then necessary permissions to this database instance and specify the use in the connection string: `User Id=username;Password=password12` instead of `Integrated Security=true;`.

```
Data Source=PNJK-SERVER;Initial Catalog=PNJKDC;User Id=username;Password=password12;
```

You need to ensure that `Mix Mode` Sql Server authentication is enabled and not just Windows Authentication for Sql Server.

If it is on a domain then you require to create a domain service account (Windows Authentication) with the necessary permissions to run the application. This will allow `Integrated Security=true` to work in most cases.